# there is error in fetching information through API.help me out

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am getting message from server to provide Auth 
{
message: "Provide the Auth Header"
}

```
let headers = {
      Token:'XXXXXX',
      Content_Type:'application/json',
      body:{
        email:'XXXX@gmail.com'
       }
   }
fetch('https://f0ztti2nsk.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v1/consignment/fetch', {
method: "POST",
body: JSON.stringify(headers),
headers: headers
})
.then(response => response.json()) 
.then(json => console.log(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are sending the correct headers and its in the correct format.